# Can I Force OutputCache to cache my custom response headers?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, outputcache

I've got an ASP.NET webform that uses output caching, and I set some custom response headers when the page is rendered (e.g. `X-MyCustomHeader`).

On a cold cache hit, my custom headers are set on the response, but subsequent cached responses don't include them.

Is there any way to cache my custom response headers along with the response body?

Comment: I think `HttpResponse.WriteSubstition` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writesubstitution(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to add custom headers.